# There is any way to save an object as a string in DynamoDB with PartiQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

Let's say I have the following object that contains a key (`body`) with a string object value:

```
{
  id:'xxyyzz',
  body:'{\'key1\':\'value1\',\'key2\':\'value2\'}'
}
```

There is any way to save it in DynamoDB with NodeJS PartiQL?

Because when I try to save it I get an error from the DynamoDB about the escaping in the string value of the body: `Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed`.

Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

You weren't clear on how you wanted to save the data, my guess was like the following:

```
const item = {
  id: 'xxyyzz',
  body: '{\'key1\':\'value1\',\'key2\':\'value2\'}'
}


const exStatement = statement => {
  ddb.executeStatement({
    Statement: statement, 
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL'
  })
    .promise() // Promise
    .then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) // On-response
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) // On-error
}

exStatement(`INSERT INTO sotest VALUE {'id' : '${item.id}', 'body' : ${item.body}}`)
```

The outcome:

[image]

### Update

```
const item = {
  id: 'lhnng-1',
  body: JSON.stringify({'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'})
}

exStatement(`INSERT INTO sotest VALUE {'id' : '${item.id}', 'body' : '${item.body}'}`)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe I wasn’t so clear.. but I want that the body won’t be an object but rather an raw string object. Is it possible?

Comment: Updated based on your needs